# crash in filling an array

Tags: c, arrays, stdio

I have written a simple program in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    int a[20], b[20];
    int n, i;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
        printf("Enter a number for a[%d]: ", j);
        scanf("%d", a[j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

This code compiles but while running when `n` is greater than 2 and when input a second number in to the array an crash occurred.

I don't underestant why it crashed, please explain it to me.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is pure and plain C not C++ (except for declaring `j` in place)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scanf` takes a *pointer* to the place in which to store the value. I.e. the address of `a[j]`. So `scanf("%d", &(a[j]) );`, or `scanf("%d", a+j);` (Remember, `a[j]` is equivalent to `*(a+j)`).

Also, there are various other issues with this. For starters, is it supposed to be `c` or `c++`? At the moment it isn't really either (although it's closer to `c`). And what happens if someone enters greater than `20`?

If you're wondering what was causing the crash, it was interpreting whatever value was in `a[j]` (which was just some uninitialised garbage) as an address, then trying to write to that (completely invalid) address. It doesn't like this, and the operating system kills your program. This is called a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).

Comment: I am newby in c and c++, in java we can give n from user and create an array with length n, only I know in c can't.

Comment: If this is `c++` and you want something like an array, but that you can specify the size from user input, or expand it whenever you like, look at [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).